# Java: does Serialization also write method code to stream for Hibernate entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, pojo

As an experiment, I fetched a Hibernate entity pojo through 'load' and wrote it to a file through normal serialization. I read that file through a separate program again through normal deserialization, and then used reflection to find the fields and the methods that the entity object's proxy class contained.

What surprised me was that it showed me all the methods that the proxy class had in it (e.g. 'getHibernateLazyInitializer()' or 'CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS(net.sf.cglib.proxy.Callback[])' etc.)

What's more, I was able to call 'getHibernateLazyInitializer()' method on the deserializaed instance! Now, if the proxy code is generated dynamically, and if that class does not exist after the JVM in which it was created shuts down, how was I able to call that method? Does the method byte code too get serialized/deserialized for Hibernate pojo's through their proxies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I debugged some more and found out that while serializing a proxied instance, Hibernate actually writes an instance of SerializableProxy. This happens because the proxy class implements an interface 'HibernateProxy' which has a 'writeReplace()' method in it which returns the said SerializableProxy instance.

When this instance is deserialized, SerializableProxy's readResolve() kicks in and returns a HibernateProxy object which is created based on the info mentioned in the SerializableProxy instance, and which uses CGLib Enhancer in turn. That's why I was able to see all those methods and call them too.

Bottom line: no method code is being written in the stream. Hibernate changes the object itself through writeReplace, and then uses readResolve and CGLIb to recreate the proxy when that object is read back.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. And if you try to deserialize an object in a Java process where the classpath does not know that class you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

As the object instance that you actually serialized was not of your entity class itself but a proxy extending that class it seems obvious that if you deserialize that you get not your entity instance back but the proxy again.

Comment: I understand that I should get back the class as proxy, but how come I'm able to see its methods, and call them? Shouldn't the proxy class cease exist once the VM that created it is shut down?